# C++ not printing to console during while loop, only after loop is finished

Tags: c++, while-loop, iostream, cout, carriage-return

**Background**
I'm currently writing some code for a naughts and crosses machine learning program based on M.E.N.A.C.E, and I have finished the code for the actual machine learning and for playing against the computer, as well as another computer to play games against it to train it. The user can enter that they'd like to let the computer train itself, and then enter the number of games to play.

**Problem**
I'm trying to make a % completion display that overwrites itself each time it updates. The issue I have is that for some reason the code won't print anything that should be printed during the while loop, instead waiting until the end to print all of it in one go. I am using '\r' (carriage return) to overwrite the last printed text. If I remove the carriage return, the while loop prints the text on each iteration like it should do. I don't have any idea what's causing this problem as I'm quite new to C++.

I am programming in Repl.it since I'm not able to install an IDE on the computer I'm using.

Here is the subroutine for calculating and displaying the % completion (using namespace std).

```
void calcCompletion(int a, int b)
{
  int completion = (static_cast<float>(a)/b) * 100;
  cout << '\r';
  cout << completion << "%";
}
```

And here is the start of the while loop where the procedure is called (mode is always 2 when I am testing this).

```
while(gamesPlayed < gameEnd)
  {
  //permutations();
  if(mode != "1")
  {
    calcCompletion(gamesPlayed, gameEnd);
  }
```

It's a very long while loop so I won't show the whole thing (hence why the curly brackets do not match up).

And here is the output:

```
 clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main ai.cpp base3.cpp main.cpp otherai.cpp permutations.cpp winCheck.cpp
 ./main
Enter mode. 
1 - Play the AI 
2 - Train the AI
2
How many games would you like the AI to play?
5

Simulating...
80%
Games complete.
Games played: 5
Games won: 1
Games lost: 0
Games drawn: 4
Win Percentage: 20%
Loss Percentage: 0%
--------------
```

It just waits until it is done with the while loop and then prints the last number, instead of printing as it goes.

I have tested trying to overwrite something I've written with no time delay in another code, it works fine so clearly being overwritten too quickly isn't the problem.

Comment: Output to `std::cout` is *buffered*. If you want to force output you need to *flush* it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude can you elaborate slightly on how that works or how to implement it? As I said I'm quite new to C++

Comment: Your beginners book or tutorial should have mentioned [I/O manipulators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) I hope? If it haven't mentioned the specific one needed to *flush* the stream then look though the list in the linked reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the curly braces of (if clause) under the while loop

Comment: I did, that's not the entire contents of the loop in the screenshot, just the IF statement.